# Condo air vent just blasting cold air all day

Tags: hvac, heating

I live in an urban condo that was built in 2006. The units have no air conditioning and electric heating. The hallways have positive pressure to keep odors inside the units. My condo has an air vent that I assume is for make-up air. This air vent blasts a large amount of cold air into the unit all day. I have to run the electric heaters basically nonstop just to maintain a livable temperature (68°F is about the max they can do running 24/7 in the winter), and that really runs up my electric bill. Is this how the building was intended to be operated? Is make-up air normally this cold?

If I block up the make-up air vent, that improves the temperature of my unit, but creates an annoyingly loud howl around the entrance door as hallway air is pushed into the unit.

Comment: Would talk with condo maintenance.  It does not sound right, because by 2006 most ventilation should be set to save heating costs.  If you wanted cold air in, a window would be need to be open/broken.

Comment: Make-up air is for combustion appliances, but electric heat requires no make-up air. Do you have any gas appliances? Can you determine the source of this air vent - does it connect directly outside, or does it come from a duct system that is pressurized somehow?

Comment: @GregHill no gas appliances. From what I read online, the make-up air is intended to reduce the pressure differential between the unit and the hallway?

Comment: If your hallway has positive pressure, wouldn't that positive pressure be heading in to your unit, meaning any vent in your unit would have air going out of it rather than into it? Also what is your climate? If it's a cold one, properly sized electric resistance heat will need to run a lot and it will be quite expensive.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have the hallway AND your condo pressurized. All I can think of is that your vent is passive and due to the cold weather you are getting a strong cold down draft from the outside air.